# Error generating App Token Facebook Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to generate a App Token.

What I understood when I read the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens), is that this is a GET call

```
GET /oauth/access_token?
     client_id={app-id}
    &client_secret={app-secret}
    &grant_type=client_credentials
```

So I decided to test it on the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/)
Having my url the following way:

```
oauth/access_token?client_id={'XXXXXXXXXXXXX'}&client_secret={'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'}&grant_type=client_credentials
```

But I'm getting this error:
The client_id I git it from the dashboard so I don't know why.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Error validating application. Invalid application ID.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 101
  }
}
```

So I don't know what I'm missing or confusing.

I have this function that's basically the same, but using the api and getting and having a different error.

**Function**

```
 function token(){
        FB.api('/oauth/access_token', 'GET', { client_id: 'xxxxxxx',client_secret: 'xxxxxxxx',grant_type: 'client_credentials' }, function(response) {
              if (!response || response.error) {
                console.log(response);
                alert('Error occured');
              } else {
                token1=response;  
                console.log(response);
              }
            });
        }
```

**Error**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: RwuSu43k_afkprBJ8BuwlCDuxdA is not defined access_token?access_token=CAAEceA3wr9MBALoGOmjrSyhJAeZCWWT301Tf5Ypl8xPL9WCgzTJbusfTPpzrda475mVQznUf…:1(anonymous function) access_token?access_token=CAAEceA3wr9MBALoGOmjrSyhJAeZCWWT301Tf5Ypl8xPL9WCgzTJbusfTPpzrda475mVQznUf…:1
Object {error: Object}error: Objectmessage: "unknown error"type: "http"__proto__: Object__proto__: Object index.html:84
```

Any idea why I'm getting this?
According to documentation, I can just pass the app id, but I want to generate the token.

> There is another method to make calls to the Graph API that doesn't
>   require using a generated app token. You can just pass your app id and
>   app secret as the access_token parameter when you make a call

Comment: why dont you just use FB.login instead of dealing with the access token on your own?

Comment: does the FB.login generates me the app token? I though only the user user token

Comment: oh, i thought you would want a user token. well, what do you need the app token for? if you only need it on the server, you can just create it like this: $app_token = APPID . '|' . APPSECRET;

Comment: I need to make a searches across pages. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#search

Answer (score 0):

Like @luschn said, an App Access Token is only the App ID concatinated with the App Secret by a pipe symbol:

```
{app_id}|{app_secret}
```

You don't need to "generate" id. You can use the app's data out of the box.